# When installing SSAS, should you install the version that corresponds to the version of SQL Server installed, or go with the newest version of SSAS?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, sql-server-2014

I am currently running SQL Server 2014 and need to install SSAS.  Is it best to match the version of SSAS to the version of SQL Server installed or is it recommended that the newest version of SSAS be installed?

---

I figure the SQL Server environment is set up one of two ways:

1) You should usually match versions of SQL Server and SSAS for compatibility reasons (they were in theory designed for each other).

2) You should usually install the newest version of SSAS because this is the current version that the SQL Server team is focusing their most time on and thus has more bug fixes, security fixes, features, etc. than older versions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question, and in this case the answer is 2:

You should install the newest version of SSAS because this is the current version that the SQL Server team is focusing their most time on and thus has more bug fixes, security fixes, features, etc. than older versions ..unless you have a version installed prior or equal to SQL 2008.

In your case of SQL 2014, install the latest version. There is no need to install the version that was released at the same time as your version of SQL Server.

See [The Installing SQL Server Analysis Services Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/install-windows/install-analysis-services) for more information.

The SSAS and SSMS teams work independantly of each other as is the case with many teams within Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

In order to offer a recommendation I need to know whether you value stability or features more?

Since SSAS is a separate instance from SQL Server it does not need to be the exact same version as SQL Server. Check out this article from Microsoft on [SSAS version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/compatibility-level-for-tabular-models-in-analysis-services).  Based on this article I would recommend you install either SSAS 2014 or SSAS 2016.

At the end of the day, the safest thing to do is install the same version of SSAS.  So if you value stability and don't want to deal with unforeseen problems down the road, I would recommend 2014.

If you want a specific feature in 2016, or just like installing the latest and greatest, then you could install 2016.

Note that I have never installed different versions of SSAS and SQL Server.

Comment: lower vesion doesn't mean "safer and more stable".  SQL 2014 still has many unsolved bugs that are solved in SQL 2016. So it's case by case.

Comment: I didn't mean that an older version has fewer bugs than a later version.  I meant that trying to connect 2 pieces of software that are the same version will be less likely to create issues.  The original question is about whether it is safer to match the version of SQL Server and SSAS.  I believe it is.

Comment: SQL Server engine acts as data source for SSAS, so the match between versions is not needed to get safer option. The choice mostly depends on features in both SQL engine and SSAS. Your link to MS site is about compatibility for SSAS projects and features, it's not about compatibilities between SQL Server and SSAS.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the latest man, go with the flow, and accept one the answers.
People take time to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can install different versions of SSAS and the SQL Server Data Engine  on the same host, yes. Should you? That completely depends on your needs. If it's a requirement that you have SSAS 2016, because it has a feature that 2014 does not, but requirement to use 2014, because 2016 breaks something else, or isn't supported, then you can do that.

There weren't a huge amount of breaking changes in SQL Server 2016 though: [Breaking changes in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016); so I'm surprised you want to go to route.

If you have SSAS 2016 and SQL Server Data Engine 2014, that's 2 sets of licences; you'll need one set for 2014 and one for 2016. If, however, you're using just one version (let's say 2016), then that's one set of licences; as your licences gives you access to all the tools that comes with that version of SQL Server (so you also get SSIS, and SSRS). That doesn't seem cost effective.

I realise that this is a question in an answer but I have to ask; Why *do* you want 2 different versions installed?